# How do I retrieve a flow and associated metadata from an org?

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, metadata, vs-code

I usually use SFDX to retrieve all of the metadata from my sandbox. I usually work on this in VSCode.

Right now I'm trying to use SFDX in VSCode to retrieve a flow so I can test that flow in another sandbox.

However, when I retrieve the data using "sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve" there is no associated metadata/xml for that flow.

And then during deployment, it says "MissingContentOrMetadataFile: Expected file at path: ..."

Does anyone know how I might properly move this flow from one sandbox to another? What is the best way?

Note: The Flow is not active.

Answer (score 11):

before retrieve and push the flows , you have to connect source org and target org from vscode using cli commands. then use below commands.

retrieve the flow from source org by using below command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:yourflowName -o sourceorg
```

push the source in to target org using below command.

```
 sfdx force:source:deploy -o targetorg
```

Comment: The CLI has been updated and the correct flag is now `-o` for specifying the source/target org.
`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:flow_api_name -o source-org-alias`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can modify your `package.xml` accordingly. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- other types removed for brevity -->
    <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```